# JumpList crash on ScrollTo

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector, jump-list

I'm asking a question because my application crash when I try to use my jumplist.
The list is filled correctly but when i try to make a jump i had

```
e.ExceptionObject {System.ArgumentException: The provided item doesn't exist in the collection.
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.ScrollTo(Object item, Nullable1 isGroup, Boolean containerViewport, Boolean setUiaFocus)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.OnJumpListClosing(Object item)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.JumpListController.BeginHide(Object selectedItem)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.JumpListController.OnSelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.set_SelectedItem(Object value)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.OnItemTap(Object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)} System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

edit : some XAML

`<phone:LongListSelector Name="ListCategorie" Margin="13,-30,0,0"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedInformation}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource orderByCategorieItemTemplate}"
                    GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource orderByCategorieGroupHeader}"
                         JumpListStyle="{StaticResource orderByCategorieJumpListStyle}" 
                                   IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                                    LayoutMode="List" 
                                    GridCellSize="480,62"
                                    SelectionChanged="ListCategorie_SelectionChanged"
                                         />`

and the jumpListStyle

```
  <Style x:Key="orderByCategorieJumpListStyle" 
           TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
        <Setter Property="LayoutMode"
                Value="List" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="12,12,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{Binding Key,Converter={StaticResource FormatConverter}}" 
                            Width="470" 
                            Height="70" 
                            Margin="6">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"
                                   Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}"                                       
                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"
                                   FontSize="28"  
                                   Padding="2"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and the creation of the list

```
   public List<KeyedList<string, Information>> GroupedInformation
    {
        get
        {
            var infs= Information.loadXml();
            infs= Information.orderByCategorie(infs);
            var GroupedInformation=
                from inf in infs
                group inf by inf.categorie into infByCat
                select new KeyedList<string, Information>(infByCat);

            return new List<KeyedList<string, Information>>(infs);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is "The provided item doesn't exist in the collection.". Do you provide actual item to scroll to?

Comment: no, everything is done automatically, the problem appeared when i change the way of fill my list, it was from a text document and now it's from an XML document

Comment: Please provide some code. Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: I hope this code can help you to help me :)

Comment: problem solved  ty  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had a function which refresh the list when the size changed, so when I go to the jumpListSelection, the app refresh the list and that's why it find the item
sorry for the inconvenience